# Ruby on Rails performance on lots of requests and DB updates per second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, amazon-web-services

I'm developing a polling application that will deal with an average of 1000-2000 votes per second coming from different users. In other words, it'll receive 1k to 2k requests per second with each request making a DB insert into the table that stores the voting data.

I'm using RoR 4 with MySQL and planning to push it to Heroku or AWS.

What performance issues related to database and the application itself should I be aware of?

How can I address this amount of inserts per second into the database?

EDIT

I was thinking in not inserting into the DB for each request, but instead writing to a memory stream the insert data. So I would have a scheduled job running every second that would read from this memory stream and generate a bulk insert, avoiding each insert to be made atomically. But i cannot think in a nice way to implement this.

Comment: You could send the request to a background job, so it will write whenever it is able to write to the database. This way, you're redirecting the user/updating the page instantly; thanking them for voting. You can use caching to save the poll stuff to memory so it doesn't have to hit the database for every person trying to vote.

Comment: @kobaltz if I send the inserts to a background queue, dont you think that this could generate a memory issue? 'cause I would be queueing 1k-2k inserts per second.

Comment: @kobaltz Also, what did you mean by caching the poll stuff? Caching the poll data and partial results so I can show it to the people trying to vote?

Comment: Assuming that there are more polls than votes, you can use caching to store the poll query to memory so the next user hitting that poll will not have to fetch the info from a DB, but rather from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can certainly do what you need to do in AWS, that high level of I/O will probably cost you.  RDS can support up to 30,000 IOPS; you can also use multiple EBS volumes in different configurations to support high IO if you want to run the database yourself.

Depending on your planned usage patterns, I would probably look at pushing into an in-memory data store, something like memcached or redis, and then processing the requests from there.  You could also look at DynamoDB, which might work depending on how your data is structured.

Are you going to have that level of sustained throughput consistently, or will it be in bursts?  Do you absolutely have to preserve every single vote, or do you just need summary data? How much will you need to scale - i.e. will you ever get to 20,000 votes per second? 200,000?

These type of questions will help determine the proper architecture.

Comment: by pushing to a in-memory data store, could it be to background queue with Redis? Dont you think that this could turns out into a memory issue?

Comment: It'll have daily peaks with this amount of throughput. What did you mean by summary data instead of preserving every single vote?

Comment: @Izolem: if you just need counts, you can push each vote into redis - presumably a vote isn't a large amount of data - and then have a backgroup process process the data from redis and update summaries, so you don't need to save each individual vote. Redis can probably handle 2k inserts into memory cheaper than 2k inserts into a database.